# How Do I Create My Own Datasets To Work With Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have found a piece of `sklearn` code that I am finding relatively straightforward to run the example Iris Dataset, but how do I create my own dataset similar to this?

`iris.data` - contains the data measurements of three types of flower 
`iris.target` - contains the labels of three types of flower

e.g. rather than analysing the three types of flower in the Iris Dataset, I would like to make my own datasets that follow this format and that I can pass through the code.

`example_sports.data` - contains the data measurements of three types of sports players 
`example_sports.target` - contains the labels of three types of sport

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris #load inbuilt dataset from sklearn
iris = load_iris() #assign variable name iris to inbuilt dataset

iris.data # contains the four numeric variables, sepal length, sepal width, petal length, petal width

print(iris.data) #printing the measurements of the Iris Dataset below


iris.target # relates to the different species shown as 0,1,2 for the three different   
            # species of Iris, a categorical variable, basically a label


print(iris.target)
```

The full code can be found at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asW8tp1qiFQ

Answer (score 2):

`sklearn` datasets are stored in `Bunch` which is basically just a type of `dict`. Sklearn `data` and `targets` are basically just NumPy arrays and can be fed into the `fit()` method of the `sklearn` estimator you are interested in. But if you want to make your own data as a `Bunch`, you can do something like the following:

```
from sklearn.utils import Bunch
import numpy as np

example_sports = Bunch(data = np.array([[1.0,1.2,2.1],[3.0,2.3,1.0],[4.5,3.4,0.5]]), target = np.array([3,2,1]))
print(example_sports.data)
print(example_sports.target)
```

Naturally, you can read your own custom lists into the `data` and `target` entries of the `Bunch`. **Pandas** is a good tool if you have the data in *Excel/CSV* files.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `type()` command whenever you are stuck. In this case it shows you that it is a Bunch object. Then you can search documentations of that class on the web and understand how to use them.

The following will help you.

```
from sklearn.utils import Bunch
b = Bunch(a=1, b="textt", c = pd.Series(np.arange(5)), d = np.asarray([0, 8, 9]))
b.c
```